# What is the policy on SE name changes and how to change it in a pinch?

Tags: support, display-names, policy

I had changed my name to Troll. At the time I did not know of the internet definition of the word troll.  After receiving lots of down votes and negativity I was then was told what it meant in a comment. I quickly wanted to changed it to something else. When I asked this question my name was troll.

What are the policies in name changing and what should you do when a mistake is in your name by misspelling or whatever so others don't get stuck like I did?

After posting this a moderator did help me change my name but xe could not do anything about the down votes:(

Comment: You used to be able to change it on another site and copy that across the network. Try that.

Comment: No need for whole MSE question for that. Just flag one of your own posts and ask for that.

Comment: If you'd care to (temporarily, if you wish) create an account on [opensource.se], I'll do it for you.

Comment: Do the down votes means: *No, don't change it back to Jen*?

Comment: @rene - I think they meant "how dared you ask, this is not the place for that, you should flag and if you didn't know before this votes will remember you next time"? -_- Jokes aside, really, even if the message was "this question show little research", did it really need **nine** downvotes?

Comment: please don't edit your posts just to bump them with useless edits.

Comment: No idea. Really. And I stopped caring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't do that. Only moderators or SE employees can do that. Please flag one of your own posts and explain in the custom flag reason why you want to change your display name.

You can also try to reset it through setting your display name on another site and click the *Save to all network accounts* button.

Comment: Why is this community wiki?

Comment: Because it is a summary of two comments on a question that shouldn't be asked here in the first place.

Comment: @Pat well, now it is kind of a generic indicator for others who want to change their display name without waiting 30 days.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be fair to take credit for the comments of others. The reason you mention is the reason I answered the question. The question itself might need some work to make it on-topic.